Connection from stomp.py to ActiveMQ Artemis fails intermittently
I'm using stomp protocol to check the health status of ActiveMQ Artemis 2.32.0. So, I have 5 brokers for which I'm sending the message and consuming it. I see some errors but intermittently for different brokers. What could be the possible reasons?
def send_message(cluster, host, password, retries_left=3):
    if retries_left == 0:
        logger.error(f"Failed to connect to {cluster} after all retries.")
        return 0

    try:
        conn = stomp.Connection([(host,61616)])
        conn.set_listener('', Listener())
        conn.set_ssl(for_hosts=[(host,61616)], ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
        conn.connect('artemis', password, wait=True)
        conn.subscribe(destination='HealthCheck::HealthCheck', id=1, ack='auto')
        conn.send(body="Health Check Message", destination='HealthCheck::HealthCheck')
        time.sleep(2)
        conn.disconnect()
        return 1
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(f"Exception occurred for cluster {cluster}")
        backoff_time = 4 - retries_left
        logger.info(f"Retrying in {backoff_time} seconds...")
        time.sleep(backoff_time)
        return send_message(cluster, host, password, retries_left - 1)

The acceptor looks like this -
<acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false;suppressInternalManagementObjects=false;sslEnabled=true;sslAutoReload=true;keyStorePath=/var/lib/artemis/security/certificate/keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=ENC(-e9049c7885c621524f7c857604318db)</acceptor>

Error -
2024-04-14 04:01:04 [ERROR]: Exception occurred for cluster dq1104
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/healthCheck.py", line 75, in send_message
    conn.connect('artemis', password, wait=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stomp/connect.py", line 151, in connect
    Protocol11.connect(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stomp/protocol.py", line 339, in connect
    self.transport.wait_for_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/stomp/transport.py", line 318, in wait_for_connection
    raise exception.ConnectFailedException()
stomp.exception.ConnectFailedException

Getting this on ActiveMQ Server
2024-04-14 06:06:04,795 ERROR [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) on acceptor "artemis" during protocol handshake with /10.1.1.126:56178 has occurred.

The whole code can be found here

It may help to enable STOMP debug logging on the broker. When you see this kind of exception then you can check the log to see if the client actually connected. If you don't see anything from that client that means the network connection failed before reaching the broker.

I'm getting a timeout on sever. Added above

The AMQ224088 log message indicates that a network connection is being made, but the client is not completing a protocol handshake. In the case of STOMP that means the client must send a CONNECT frame. This apparently isn't happening. You might trying using a TCP packet sniffer to see exactly what's happening on the connection.

STOMP is giving random behavior when the interval for health check is less than 1 min, like 30 sec

By "STOMP" do you mean the Python client you're using?

Yes, the python library. When the interval is less more than 1 min, it works fine.(tried for 24hrs)

Did you ever get this sorted out?

No, not yet still finding
